# Disable PCI ACS (Access Control Services)

Tags: linux, drivers, pci

The vendor of a custom PCIe video encoder says we should disable ACS - Access Control Services - on our machine for proper operation of the card driver.

They haven't said how to do that.

[This post above NVIDIA GPUs](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/883054/cuda-programming-and-performance/multi-gpu-peer-to-peer-access-failing-on-tesla-k80-/2) says to use the `setpci` command, but since we're not using NVIDIA and have a different motherboard, the device addresses would be different (I guess).

For example,

`setpci -s 02:01.0 f2a.w=0000` doesn't do anything...

**EDIT II**
For example:

```
# setpci -v -s 02:04.0 220.w
0000:02:04.0 @220 = 000d
# setpci -v -s 02:04.0 220.w=0000
0000:02:04.0 @220 0000
# setpci -v -s 02:04.0 220.w
0000:02:04.0 @220 = 000d
```

How do you find the register addresses given the actual PCI bridges on my motherboard?

The (trimmed) output of `lspci -vvv` is below.

**EDIT**

Sorry, forgot the OS info:

32-bit Centos6, kernel 4.4.127-1.el6.elrepo.i686 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 09:44:43 EDT 2018 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

```
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a114 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport


00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a115 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-

02:01.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor Device b608 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: [220 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl+ DirectTrans+
        ACSCtl: SrcValid+ TransBlk- ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-

02:02.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor Device b608 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: [220 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl+ DirectTrans+
        ACSCtl: SrcValid+ TransBlk- ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-

02:03.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor Device b608 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: [220 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl+ DirectTrans+
        ACSCtl: SrcValid+ TransBlk- ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-

02:04.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor Device b608 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Capabilities: [220 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl+ DirectTrans+
        ACSCtl: SrcValid+ TransBlk- ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
```

Comment: It's not an NVIDIA problem; it's a PCI switch problem. (The devices you are looking for are among `lspci -d ::0604` and I do not believe they are ever from NVIDIA.) @LarryC's answer is very good and you should accept it IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you like to try this, and see if the output improves?

```
setpci -v -s 02:04.0 ecap_acs+6.w
setpci -v -s 02:04.0 ecap_acs+6.w=0
setpci -v -s 02:04.0 ecap_acs+6.w
```

**EDIT 1** : Your  `setpci`  commands were going to the ACS Extended Capability; but then were *not* following the right offset ( **6** ) for the **ACS Control Register**

**EDIT 2** : If you want to see how the  **setpci**  utility is processing the PCI Express Capabilities and Extended Capabilities, while you are ever working on troubleshooting access to one of your hardware ports or devices ... another interesting view is by adding the  `-G`  option.  This is not generally productive, but as you can see here, it gives a view of how the entire **Capabilities** and **Extended Capabilities** lists are traversed.  Example, on a Root Port --

```
user@host:~$ sudo setpci -G -v -s 00:01.1 ecap_acs+6.w
Trying method linux-sysfs......using /sys/bus/pci...OK
Decided to use linux-sysfs
0000:00:01.1 0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0001 of type 1 at 0050
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0010 of type 1 at 0058
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0005 of type 1 at 00a0
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 000d of type 1 at 00c0
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0008 of type 1 at 00c8
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0001 of type 1 at 0050
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0010 of type 1 at 0058
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0005 of type 1 at 00a0
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 000d of type 1 at 00c0
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0008 of type 1 at 00c8
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 000b of type 2 at 0100
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0001 of type 2 at 0150
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0019 of type 2 at 0270
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 000d of type 2 at 02a0
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 001e of type 2 at 0370
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 001d of type 2 at 0380
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0025 of type 2 at 0400
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0026 of type 2 at 0410
0000:00:01.1: Found capability 0027 of type 2 at 0440
(ecap 000d @2a0) @2a6 = 0000
```